# SAS: Avoid end-of-line problem and LOST CARD

Tags: sas

I'm working through a SAS exercise, which has data in the following format:

```
3496 Jerry         Nelson        13960 Wilson Dr.         San Diego                     CA   92191  40   4
3498 Scott         Mason         9226 College Dr.         Oak View                      CA   93022  95   2
3498                                                                                    CA          35   3
3498                                                                                    CA          35   11
3500 Michele       Stone         8393 West Ct.            Emeryville                    CA   94608  55   5
3500                                                                                    CA          70   5
```

For each person, the data continues until the next person's name. The following code is very close to what I need, I think:

```
libname Ch4data '\\Client\C$\Users\m210028\Google Drive\Adrian\Self-Study\SAS\Chapter4_data';

Data Ch4data.my_donations;
    Infile '\\Client\C$\Users\m210028\Google Drive\Adrian\Self-Study\SAS\Chapter4_data\Donations.dat' MISSOVER;
    Array   amounts(10);
    Array   months(10);
    Input   first_name      $  6 -  19 
            last_name       $ 20 -  33
            street_address  $ 34 -  58
            city            $ 59 -  88
            state_code      $ 89 -  93
            zip_code        $ 94 - 100
            amounts(1)       101 - 105 @ 106 
            months(1);
    end = end1;
    If ~(end1) Then
    Do;
        Input   test_char $ 6-6 @;
        i = 2;
        Do While (0 = ANYALPHA(test_char));
            Input   amounts(i)   101 - 105 @ 106 
                    months(i);
            end = end1;
            If ~(end1) Then Input test_char $ 6-6 @;
            Else test_char = '';
            i = i+1;
        End; 
    End;
Run;

Proc Print Data = Ch4data.my_donations;
    Title 'Donations to Coastal Humane Society';
Run;
```

The problem is that I'm getting a LOST CARD note in the log, and the last name in the file, Michele Stone, doesn't make it into the data set. I suspect my code for detecting the end-of-file is incorrect. Could someone please show me how to detect the end-of-file? The SAS documentation is not helpful.

Many thanks for your time!

[UPDATE]: Thanks to Tom's comment, I can now get the last line with the following code:

```
libname Ch4data '\\Client\C$\Users\m210028\Google Drive\Adrian\Self-Study\SAS\Chapter4_data';

Data Ch4data.my_donations;
    Infile '\\Client\C$\Users\m210028\Google Drive\Adrian\Self-Study\SAS\Chapter4_data\Donations.dat' MISSOVER END=end1;
    Array   amounts(10);
    Array   months(10);
    Input   first_name      $  6 -  19 
            last_name       $ 20 -  33
            street_address  $ 34 -  58
            city            $ 59 -  88
            state_code      $ 89 -  93
            zip_code        $ 94 - 100
            amounts(1)       101 - 105 @ 106 
            months(1);
    If ~(end1) Then
    Do;
        Input   test_char $ 6-6 @;
        i = 2;
        Do While (0 = ANYALPHA(test_char));
            Input   amounts(i)   101 - 105 @ 106 
                    months(i);
            If ~(end1) Then Input test_char $ 6-6 @;
            Else test_char = '';
            i = i+1;
        End; 
    End;
Run;

Proc Print Data = Ch4data.my_donations;
    Title 'Donations to Coastal Humane Society';
Run;
```

Unfortunately, it's not getting the second-to-last line. For that matter, it's skipping a lot of first lines of records. Thoughts?

Comment: You did not include the END= option on your INFILE statement.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, that gets me the last line, now, but now I'm not getting the second-to-last line! Updated code forthcoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to combine reading and transposing. It is probably easier to read first and then transpose.  In fact you can just read

```
data step1;
    Infile example truncover ;
    Input   first_name      $  6 -  19 
            last_name       $ 20 -  33
            street_address  $ 34 -  58
            city            $ 59 -  88
            state_code      $ 89 -  93
            zip_code        $ 94 - 100
            amount           101 - 105 
            month            105 - 110
    ;
    if not missing(first_name) then case+1;
run;
```

and then apply the carry-forward of the names etc.

```
data step2;
  update step1(obs=0) step1;
  by case;
  output;
run;
```

and then transpose.

```
data want;
   do row=1 by 1 until(last.case);
     set step2;
     by case;
     array months [10];
     array amounts [10];
     months[row]=month;
     amounts[row]=amount;
  end;
  drop row amount month;
run;
```

Comment: Is the months data supposed to be present? I see only blank columns.

Comment: Works with the data you posted. Make sure to use TRUNCOVER instead of (older less useful) MISSOVER option.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the line holding specifier `@@` to hold the line when your name check detects the first line of the next group.

```
filename exercise 'c:\temp\exercise.txt';

* create file to read in;    
data _null_;
  file exercise; 
  input;
  put _infile_;
datalines;
3496 Jerry         Nelson        13960 Wilson Dr.         San Diego                     CA   92191  40   4
3498 Scott         Mason         9226 College Dr.         Oak View                      CA   93022  95   2
3498                                                                                    CA          35   3
3498                                                                                    CA          35   11
3500 Michele       Stone         8393 West Ct.            Emeryville                    CA   94608  55   5
3500                                                                                    CA          70   5
run;

* read-in the data;
* error will occur if data file has a group with more than 10 months of data;
data want;
    infile exercise end=end_of_data ;

    array   amounts(10);
    array   months(10);

    input   first_name      $  6 -  19 
            last_name       $ 20 -  33
            street_address  $ 34 -  58
            city            $ 59 -  88
            state_code      $ 89 -  93
            zip_code        $ 94 - 100
            amounts(1)       101 - 105 
@ 106       months(1);

    do i = 2 by 1 while (not end_of_data);
      input name_check $ 6-6 @@;
      if name_check = ' ' then 
        input amounts(i) 101-105 @106 months(i);
      else
        leave;  /* jump out of loop
                 * when control returns to top the input will be of the held line
                 */
    end;
run;
```